# How to access a quoted property in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is a object declaration: `var o = {"foo-bar": 24}`
Then, my question is how to access the property?

---

I forget it that I can access a object's property by using square brackets...

Comment: Really? Have you checked on Google???

Comment: I think this question must be there in this week's "Stack Overflow Weekly Newsletter" mail.

Comment: I just thought in a java programming way. I just tried to access the property in a java convention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var o = {"foo-bar": 24};
    alert(o['foo-bar']);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DragosBobolea : Mind your language,will you?

Answer (score 3):

Use square brackets:

```
o['foo-bar']
```